# Android MapView doesn't show the map at zoom level 1

Tags: android, android-mapview, zooming

I have a problem with android map view.

I try to develop simple app with map and I don't understand what happen with map when zoom level is 1. `MapView` show nothing if `zoom == 1`. What is cause of this problem?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mapview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="api_key"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you checked with different zoom level?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work only at zoom level 1.

Comment: It's look like on this image http://imgur.com/DUSaf

Comment: you should avoid zoom level 1..

Comment: How can I avoid zoom level 1 and disable zoom out button ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) {
        super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
        if (mapView.getZoomLevel() < 2)
            mapView.getController().setZoom(2);
    }
```

> In your mapview class check condition.

Comment: This avoid zoom level 1, but zoom out button still enabled.

Comment: you can disable also. ..zoom out button so..you can defined as same conditon  if (mapView.getZoomLevel() < 18)
            mapView.getController().setZoom(18);}

Comment: Another question: can I replace map image at zoom level 1 with my own image?